# calling functions in robotium

Tags: android, robotium

How robotium is calling **functions** written in the **test class**. I have written many **functions** in the test class.   i **dont** want to call every functions . I just want to call some functions in some specific **conditions**.  like we are doing in programming languages.How can i do this? I have noticed that even if we are not calling every functions written in test class are executing.  *why it is like that?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the robotium, but test framework. The instrumentation test runner just goes through the class and call all public methods of a test class.

Comment: Move your utility methods to another class which doesn't extend AndroidTestCase or similiar.

Comment: actually every functions are not utility methods.some og them are testmethods.but i need to invoke those methods only after finishing the previous methods.

Comment: @seethalakshmi any update on how you implemented this?